# html is reading php tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

how to write php code in html, the html is reading the php tag

```
while($value = mysqli_fetch_array($result33))
 {
   $output .=
    '
      <tr>
      <td>
       '.$value['co_name'].'
      </td>
      <td>
       <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs btn-group">

       <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" 
         onclick="openmymodel('.$value['id'].', 
           <?php '.$value['co_name'].' ?>, <?php 
           '.$value['eco_name'].' ?>)">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-120"></i>
       </button>

       <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" 
          onclick="confirm_modal('.$value['id'].')">
         <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-120"></i>
       </button>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
    ';
   }
```

the problem is html is reading the php tag inside the "openmymodel function"

Comment: You are already in PHP doing string concatenation. `onclick="openmymodel('.$value['id'].'<?php '.$value['co_name'].' ?>` should be `onclick="openmymodel(' . $value['id'] . $value['co_name'] . '...`

Comment: sorry but if i did as you said it gives this error, (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' )

Comment: @Walid While this may seem like semantics, HTML is written in PHP but PHP is not written in HTML. You are in PHP writing out HTML code. There is no need to use <?php ?> because you're already in PHP.

Comment: using heredoc may help a bit.  You won't have to deal with the quote issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your delimiter is a `'`, not a `<?php` tag which is actually what you are using.

If you pay some attention to the syntax highlighter, you can see that `<?php` is in the same color as the rest of the string.

> *That means it is not being detected as a sentence.*

```php
while($value = mysqli_fetch_array($result33))
 {
   $output .=
    '
      <tr>
      <td>
       '.$value['co_name'].'
      </td>
      <td>
       <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs btn-group">

       <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" 
         onclick="openmymodel(
           '.$value['id'].', 
           \''.$value['co_name'].'\', 
           \''.$value['eco_name'].'\')">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-120"></i>
       </button>

       <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" 
          onclick="confirm_modal('.$value['id'].')">
         <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-120"></i>
       </button>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
    ';
   }
```

> Notice by yourself how the syntax highlight now changes.

Comment: sorry but i still have the same problem

Comment: @Walid Might another line outside the scope you provided be the issue? Or what error are you exactly getting after removing the previously mentioned error?

Comment: The problem is im writing php inside html inside php so so i have to use this tag [ '.$value['id'].' ]  so the html is not reading this ' '

Comment: the error is that (1, star, star).... i have to get something like that (1, 'star' , 'star')

Comment: @k3llydev `$value['co_name']` and `$value['eco_name']` will probably need to get wrapped in quotes as well for their values to properly be passed into `openmymodel`

Comment: @Walid You can try: `\''.$value['co_name'].'\'`. This will escape one quote so PHP doesn't misunderstand. I edited my answer fixing this.

Comment: Yeah, just missing quotes. If you are not using some IDE or something with syntax highlighting it is very easy to get lost when writing these. Break it out, start small, combine. Read up on [topic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Lots of ways to go about it, some much more readable than others.... eg. `"is '{$nice}'"`

Comment: @k3llydev  Thank you very much \''.$value['co_name'].'\'  worked well

Comment: @Walid Always glad to help. I would recommend reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Happy coding!